# Toast notification to a user device when the device offline

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-storage, azure-queues

I send toast notification to user device app ,when the user device is offline or temporarily lost connection or locked.The user device not receive the toast notification after its come to online. How can i received toast notifications after the device connected.

I using this code to sent notification

```
push.wns.sendToastText01(result.channel)
```

Please help me.How can i received toast notifications after the device connected.